Get all properties with a custom attribute for external assembly
Topics I've read:
How to get a list of properties with a given attribute?
Reflection - get attribute name and value on property

I created an external assembly(Class Library) and I defined a class and a custom attribute in it:
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class MyCustomAttribute:Attribute
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public int MyProperty0 { get; set; }

        [MyCustom(Message ="aaa")]
        public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }

        [MyCustom(Message = "bbb")]
        public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    
        public int MyProperty3 { get; set; }
    }
}

For first goal I want to get all properties with MyCustomAttribute for Class1 and I wrote this code:
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(<file path>);
var props = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1").GetProperties().Where(
prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(ClassLibrary1.MyCustomAttribute)));

but it returned null for props. I changed the code this way:
PropertyInfo[] props = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1").GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);
    foreach (object attr in attrs)
    {
        var authAttr = attr as ClassLibrary1.MyCustomAttribute; <--------
        if (authAttr != null)
        {
            string propName = prop.Name;
            string message = authAttr.Message;

            Console.WriteLine($"{propName} ... {message }");
        }
    }
}

but the specified line returned null for attr. but it actually is type of ClassLibrary1.MyCustomAttribute:


I can't figure out what is the problem.

Why are you loading the assembly using Assembly.LoadFile? Since you are able to write ClassLibrary1.MyCustomAttribute, why not just write typeof(ClassLibrary1.Class1) as well?

@Sweeper: This is a test code but in real problem I should load assembly based on user decision.

Is the choice of MyCustomAttribute also based on user decision? Or is it declared somewhere that both your code and the user-chosen assembly both reference?

I think Attribute.IsDefined(prop, assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.MyCustomAttribute")) might work for this particular case. The type you get by writing typeof(ClassLibrary1.MyCustomAttribute) is not exactly the same as the one in the loaded assembly.

@Sweeper: Thanks that works. How can I change my second solution? I try this:attr as assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.MyCustomAttribute")); but it has error. Could you please write your solution as an answer.

Evidently, the type name ClassLibrary1.MyCustomAttribute in your code does not represent the same type as declared in the assembly you loaded, even if they have the same namespace and simple name.
You will get the correct type using assembly.GetType, in the same way you get the Type representing Class1.
var props = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1").GetProperties().Where(
    prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.MyCustomAttribute"))
);

To get Message, use reflection,
var attributeType = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.MyCustomAttribute");
var messageProperty = attributeType.GetProperty("Message");
object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);
foreach (object attr in attrs)
{
    if (attributeType.IsInstanceOfType(attr))
    {
        string propName = prop.Name;
        string message = messageProperty.GetValue(attr);

        Console.WriteLine($"{propName} ... {message }");
    }
}

